# Is there any bad side-effect if modify prototype?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write a routing framework of nodejs, I need to add some helper methods for ServerRequest and ServerResponse. I notice express has change it way from modify prototype to

express/response.js

```
var res = module.exports = {
  __proto__: http.ServerResponse.prototype
};

res.redirect = function (url) {
  ...
}
```

And express/middlewares.js

```
expressInit = function(req, res, next) {
  // ...
  res.__proto__ = app.response;
  next()
}
```

But in my framework, I just like to do it simple:

```
http.ServerResponse.prototype.redirect = function(url) {
  ...
}
```

I don't know if there is something I don't know of why express change the style of override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the [`__proto__` pseudo-attribute is non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto) so it's use was never really appropriate; moreover, it is now considered "deprecated" according to the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN).

However, the [`prototype` property of Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype) is a standard part of the language and its use is always safe.

Always use `MyFunction.prototype`, never use `myObject.__proto__`.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it the Express way only modifies the response object for that instance of ServerResponse.  Your method will globally add the redirect function to every response created by any server in your node process.

If you were running multiple frameworks and servers inside your node process, or wanted to share your code with other people who might be doing so, that might be an issue as another framework might also add a redirect function and there will be clash.  Generally, it is considered bad style to modify objects you don't own.

The Express way does come with a [performance penalty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24833201/563811), but presumably there is a worse performance penalty for doing it any other way.