# What is the specific impact of assigning __proto__ in each browser?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, safari, prototype

This is for a very specific use case. And this is all in typescript (which for this use case I think it has no impact but I mention it in case it does).

We have our main code and a single web worker for background processing. We use the Worker.postMessage() to post messages back and forth. We always call postMessage(myData) where myData is an object. That object has member variables that are objects that have member variables that are objects... It's a lot of objects being passed across.

When we call postMessage() what we receive on the other side is the submitted object, but just the data. The methods (ie the prototype) is not passed across. The web worker communication serializes the data and rebuilds it, just the data, on the far side. Looking at the **proto** for the delivered object, it is an Object as far as I can tell, but just a basic object.

So, what appears to be the most sensible approach is to just walk all the objects setting the **proto** on them ([discussed some here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302812/assign-proto-to-an-interface-to-turn-it-into-an-object-clever-or-dangerous)). This avoids re-creating every object again in a copy constructor (which takes time, doubles the memory hit, and increases the work for the garbage collector). And it seems like a reasonable thing to do because we're just reapplying the prototypes it had on the sent side. (And in ES6 browsers we'll use setPrototypeOf().)

My question is, what is the specific hit for the following browsers. What impact does it have for these specific ones (all we care about are the recent versions because we must have web workers):

- Internet Explorer 10 & 11?
- Chrome 34 & 35?
- Safari 7?

And in the case of Firefox - [it doesn't like it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

Is it a hit for IE, Chrome, & Safari? And if so, exactly what/how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is - bad in Chrome & Opera, very bad in Firefox, horribly bad in IE. We did performance testing of copy constructors vs setting the prototype.

[Details here:](http://windward.net/blogs/high-performance-javascript-assign-prototypes/#.U8mAePldV8G)

[image]