# Is this a way to pass full objects between web worker threads?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I've read [2.7.6 Safe passing of structured data](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#safe-passing-of-structured-data) several times and I still am not understanding exactly what this means. Is this a way to pass a complete object, including retaining its prototype, between web worker threads (or in our case between the main and a worker thread)?

If so, that would avoid [the issues trying to rebuild the prototype in each object passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296576/what-is-the-specific-impact-of-assigning-proto-in-each-browser).

Comment: Passing big object graphs back and forth between contexts sounds like a fundamental design mistake to me. It's going to be expensive no matter what you do.

Comment: "8. If deep clone is set to own, then, for each enumerable own property in input, run the following steps ... blah blah blah" this doesn't even copy inherited properties not to speak about `__proto__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is - copy constructors. We did performance testing of copy constructors vs setting the prototype and copy constructors were faster. A little faster in Chrome & Opera, worlds faster in IE and Firefox.

[image]